# how to send data from table to jsp

Tags: java, html, css

I want to get table data from table to new database through `jsp` servlet this is my sample code in `jsp` this table contains database elements

I struggled for a week. Please help me.

I want to get table data from table to new database through `jsp` servlet this is my sample code in `jsp` this table contains database elements

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="Servlets.Db"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Place your Order</h1>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <form action="order" method="post">
          <!--
            <label>name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" >    
            <label>Member Id</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="memberid" type="text" >
            <label>Orders</label>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotron">
          -->
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>quantity</th>
            </tr>

            <%
              Connection con=Db.getCon();
              String sql="SELECT * FROM drugs";
              PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
              ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
              while(rs.next()) {
            %>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<%=rs.getInt("id") %>"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<%=rs.getString("name") %>"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="quntity"></td>
            </tr>

            <%
              }
            %>
          </table>
          <input type="submit" value="submit order">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <%@ include file="WEB-INF/Footer.jsp" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you get? I would recommend choosing a framework that helps you and search for a tutorial for that (Spring Boot for example).

Comment: can you give me good tutorial links..

Comment: i received some database syntax error but their everything seems okay

Comment: Those database syntax errors should lead you the way ;-) Or at least it would help anyone trying to help you.
Try a search for 'Spring Boot Tutorial' -> https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-crud-spring-boot-20-minutes https://www.udemy.com/spring-boot-tutorial-for-beginners/

Comment: thanx lot friend

Answer (score 0):

The work you done is get data from database and show data in jsp,if you want to put data into database,you should change sql to "add" and jsp to "input".